# Trim while sorting List

Tags: c#, list, sorting, datagridview, trim

I am reading lines from a semicolon separated file and I found here how to sort a List:

```
IEnumerable<string> sSortedList = sList.Select(line => new
{
    SortKey1 = line.Split(';')[4].Trim(),
    SortKey2 = line.Split(';')[1].Trim(),
    Line = line

})
.OrderBy(Section => Section.SortKey1)
.ThenBy(StdName => StdName.SortKey2)
.Select(sResult => sResult.Line);
```

I had to use trim in sortkeys because if I don't, I will not get them sorted correctly..

Anyway, when I need to copy the list to another one, or write them into a DataGridView, I have to use trim again:

```
foreach (string sLine in sSortedList)
{
    if (sLine.Contains("3"))
    {
         dataGridView1.InvokeEx(control => control.Rows.Add(sLine.Split(';').Select(sCol => sCol.Trim()).ToArray<string>()));
         listBox1.InvokeEx(control => control.Items.Add("Processed Line: " + sLine));
    }
}
```

I don't want to trim the fields while filling the DataGridView, I just want to trim all fields while sorting, is this possible?

Comment: You are returning to you sorted list whole line, which you are not trimming. I think you cannot do this in the other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store your data in a more specialised object:

```
internal class ProcessedLine
{
    public string Original {get; private set;}
    public string[] Trimmed {get; private set;}

    public ProcessedLine(string original)
    {
        Original = original;
        Trimmed = original.Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
    }

    public string SortKey1
    {
        get{ return Trimmed[4]; }
    }

    public string SortKey2
    {
        get{ return Trimmed[1]; }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var processedLines = sList.Select(x => new ProcessedLine(x)).ToList();

foreach (var processedLine in processedLines.OrderBy(x => x.SortKey1).ThenBy(x => x.SortKey2))
{
    if (lineObject.Original.Contains("3"))
    {
        dataGridView1.InvokeEx(control => control.Rows.Add(lineObject.Trimmed));
        listBox1.InvokeEx(control => control.Items.Add("Processed Line: " + lineObject.Original));
    }
}
```

Please note that I wouldn't recommend this. (Also, I'm not 100% sure it works, haven't tested it but you can see what the concepts are.)

IMHO you'd be better off if you'd convert your line first to a more meaningful object, for example by using [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/). Sorting on "the fourth part of a splitted string" is essentially meaningless and is IMHO bad code, since it requires you to figure out the format of the input file; converting a line into an object with meaning (e.g. the first part is the ID, the third part is the Name, etc) allows you to write more meaningful code.

BTW Microsoft [doesn't like Hungarian notation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx) WRT to C#: the "s" at the start of sList and sSortedList etc. Also, I'd advice against naming something a "sortedList" when [it isn't one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `Trimmed = original.Select(x => x.Split(';')).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList()`

produces the following error: 'char' doesn't contain a definition for 'Split'

Comment: Ah, indeed yes. Fixed it.

Comment: thanks, this worked with one modification:

`dataGridView1.InvokeEx(control => control.Rows.Add(processedLine.Trimmed.ToArray()));`

I had to add ToArray(), otherwise the first column is filled with:
System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]


Anyway, do I really have to use ToList() in this line:

`var processedLines = sList.Select(x => new ProcessedLine(x)).ToList();`

and why? Also, why did I have to use ToArray() although in the class you used ToList() in this line:

`Trimmed = Original.Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();`

Comment: You can change `List<string> Trimmed` to `string[] Trimmed` and then do `Trimmed = original.Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();`; that way you have the correct type you need. I'd assumed List<string> would be OK, but it is possible there's still some objects that expect an array, and then a List<T> won't work.

Comment: BTW Don't forget to accept the answer if it has solved your problem. ;-)

Comment: of course I will, I edited your answer to reflect the changes from the comemnts. Still I have a question, why do you use ToList() in this line:

`var processedLines = sList.Select(x => new ProcessedLine(x)).ToList();`

It works without ToList() anyway, so what difference does it make, and why does it work with or without it!?

In my original code, I should have used string[] from the beginning, now I know where I did the mistake.

Could you please recommend sth I can read in order to start thinking and learning how to turn my code into objects as you did in your answer for c#?

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter, but .Select() "suffers" from [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx). WRT reading suggestions: I've learned those kind of things on the job, mostly by looking at existing code, by being part of a team and learning through code reviews,... Telerik has [some good tips](http://www.slideshare.net/nakov/writing-high-quality-code-in-c).

Comment: If I omit ToList() Select(..) will suffer the deferred execution. I traced through the code and noticed that the query is executed once it enters the foreach loop, while if ToList() is added to the line, it will force the query to be executed once the processedLines object is created.

That's a good point, thanks for all the help you provided.

Comment: If I wanted to use `File.WriteAllLines(..)` to save the new trimmed lines into a file, is the right way to do it is to add a function to the class:
`public string JoinTrimmedFields()
{
return string.Join(";", Trimmed);
}`

How can I build, or return a List<string> from this class in order to use it in `File.WriteAllLines(..)`

Comment: Doesn't even need to be a function, could just be a property like SortKey1, e.g. `public string JoinedTrimmed { return string.Join(";", Trimmed); }`. The `List<string>` you need can be retrieved by `processedLines.Select(x =>x.JoinedTrimmed).ToList();`

Comment: I changed sList name to AllLinesfromFilestoList as you recommended.

Then, to create a new trimmed/sorted list from AllLinesfromFilestoList, I did this:

`List<string> TrimmedLines = AllLinesfromFilestoList.Select(x => new ProcessedLine(x)).OrderBy(x => x.SortKey1).ThenBy(x => x.SortKey2).Select(x => x.JoinedTrimmed).ToList();
File.WriteAllLines("trimmed List.txt", TrimmedLines, Encoding.UTF8);`

Actually, using ToList, prevents deferred execution, thanks to your notes.

Answer (score 0):

@BCdotNET I managed to edit your class as per the past  comments and created my own class as you suggested to encapsulate the whole process as much as possible, I am still thinking about how to encapsulate the csv field names in order to make it more general, I still need more ideas:

```
    internal class ProcessedLine
    {
        public string Original { get; private set; }
        public string[] Trimmed { get; private set; }

        public ProcessedLine(string original)
        {
            Original = original;
            Trimmed = Original.Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
        }

        public string SortKey1
        {
            get { return Trimmed[4]; }
        }

        public string SortKey2
        {
            get { return Trimmed[1]; }
        }

        public string JoinedTrimmed
        {
            get { return string.Join(";", Trimmed); }
        }
    }
```

Here is my class:

```
    internal class ReadAllLinesFromFilesInDirectory
    {
        private List<string> AllPlainLinesFromAllFiles = new List<string>();
        private List<string> SortedJoinedTrimmedAllLines = new List<string>();

        public ReadAllLinesFromFilesInDirectory(string directoryPath, string TopicName, string LinesToExclude)
        {
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, TopicName + "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".csv", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
            foreach (string fileEntry in fileEntries)
            {
                List<string> ReadLinesFromFileToList = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(fileEntry, Encoding.Default)
                    .Where(x => !x.Contains(LinesToExclude))
                    .ToList());
                for (int lineCount = 0; lineCount < ReadLinesFromFileToList.Count(); lineCount++)
                {
                    ReadLinesFromFileToList[lineCount] = String.Format("{0};{1}", ReadLinesFromFileToList[lineCount], Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileEntry).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToUpper());
                }
                AllPlainLinesFromAllFiles.AddRange(ReadLinesFromFileToList);
            }
        }

        public List<string> SortedJoinedTrimmedAllLinesToList()
        {

            SortedJoinedTrimmedAllLines = AllPlainLinesFromAllFiles
                .Select(x => new ProcessedLine(x))
                .OrderBy(x => x.SortKey1)
                .ThenBy(x => x.SortKey2)
                .Select(x => x.JoinedTrimmed)
                .ToList();
            return SortedJoinedTrimmedAllLines;
        }

        public List<string> ToList()
        {
            return AllPlainLinesFromAllFiles;
        }
    }
```

I use it this way:

```
        this.InvokeEx(x => x.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = columnHeader.Split(';').Count<string>());
        List<string> AllLinesFromAllFilesToListTrimmedSorted = new ReadAllLinesFromFilesInDirectory("StudentList", "IT102-Cplus-Section", "StudentID").SortedJoinedTrimmedAllLinesToList();

        this.InvokeEx(x => x.toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0);
        this.InvokeEx(x => x.toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = AllLinesFromAllFilesToListTrimmedSorted.Count());

        foreach (string singleLine in AllLinesFromAllFilesToListTrimmedSorted)
        {
            this.InvokeEx(x => x.toolStripProgressBar1.Value++);
            this.InvokeEx(x => x.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = x.toolStripProgressBar1.Value.ToString());
            this.InvokeEx(x => x.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(singleLine.Split(';')));
            this.InvokeEx(x => x.listBox1.Items.Add("Processed Line: " + singleLine));
        }
```

Actually, I am not used to writing classes, hope this first real try is OK. I need more comments to see if there is a better way to do it.

BTW, FileHelpers is only for .NET 1.1 and 2.0, there is not .NET 4.5 support, what a pitty for this excellent one..